# Fluent NHibernate - Save NEW parent object with NEW List<object> children

Tags: nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I create the 'Parent' object. The parent object contains a list of 'Children' objects.

When I save the parent, I expect the children objects also to be saved but only the Parent is saved to the database.

FluentNHibernate version is 1.2.0.712

NHibernate version is 3.1.0.4000

My Mapping and Models are below.

**Parent Model**

```
namespace Models 
{  
    public class OpenSale 
    {
        public OpenSale() 
        {
            OpenSaleItems = new List<OpenSaleItem>();
        }

    public virtual int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual int StaffID { get; set; }
    public virtual int TillID { get; set; }
    public virtual int? FloorTableID { get; set; }
    public virtual int LocationID { get; set; }
    public virtual System.DateTime TimeStarted { get; set; }
    public virtual System.Nullable<System.DateTime> TimeCompleted { get; set; }
    public virtual int? TenderTypeID { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal AmountPaid { get; set; }
    public virtual char SaleCompleted { get; set; }
    public virtual char CompletedOffline { get; set; }
    public virtual string Surname { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal TotalVAT { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<OpenSaleItem> OpenSaleItems { get; set; }
}
```

}

**Parent Map**

```
    using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;
    using Models;

    namespace Maps
    {
      public class OpenSaleMap : ClassMap<OpenSale>
      {
        public OpenSaleMap()
        {
        Table("OpenSale");

        Id(x => x.ID).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("ID");

        Map(x => x.TimeStarted).Column("TimeStarted").Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.TimeCompleted).Column("TimeCompleted");
        Map(x => x.TenderTypeID).Column("TenderTypeID").Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Surname).Column("Surname").Length(30);
        Map(x => x.Amount).Column("Amount").Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.AmountPaid).Column("AmountPaid").Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.SaleCompleted).Column("SaleCompleted").Not.Nullable().Length(1);
        Map(x => x.CompletedOffline).Column("CompletedOffline").Not.Nullable().Length(1);
        Map(x => x.TotalVAT).Column("TotalVAT").Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.StaffID).Column("StaffID");
        Map(x => x.TillID).Column("TillID");
        Map(x => x.FloorTableID).Column("FloorTableID");
        Map(x => x.LocationID).Column("LocationID");

        // WORKS BUT SAVES OPENSALE ONLY
        // HasMany(x => x.OpenSaleItems).KeyColumn("OpenSaleID").Inverse();
        // HasMany(x => x.OpenSaleItems).Cascade.All().KeyColumn("OpenSaleID").Inverse();
        // HasMany(x => x.OpenSaleItems).KeyColumn("OpenSaleID").Inverse();
        // HasMany(x => x.OpenSaleItems).KeyColumn("OpenSaleID");
        // HasMany(x => x.OpenSaleItems).Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan().Table("OpenSaleItem").LazyLoad().KeyColumn("OpenSaleID");


        //HasMany(x => x.OpenSaleItems).Cascade.All().KeyColumn("OpenSaleID");
        // HasMany(x => x.OpenSaleItems).Cascade.SaveUpdate().KeyColumn("OpenSaleID");
        //HasMany(x => x.OpenSaleItems).Inverse().KeyColumn("OpenSaleID");
        // HasMany(x => x.OpenSaleItems).Cascade.All().Table("OpenSaleItem").LazyLoad();
        // HasMany(x => x.OpenSaleItems).Cascade.SaveUpdate().Table("OpenSaleItem");

        //HasMany(x => x.OpenSaleItems).Cascade.All().Table("OpenSaleItem");
        //HasMany(x => x.OpenSaleItems).Table("OpenSaleItem");

        HasMany(x => x.OpenSaleItems)
   .Cascade.All()
   .KeyColumn("OpenSaleID")
   .Inverse() // this is the way how to manage insertions
   .Not
   .LazyLoad();

    }
}
```

}

**Child Model**

```
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Text; 
using System; 

namespace Models 
{ 
  public class OpenSaleItem 
  {
    public OpenSaleItem() 
    {
    }

    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual int OpenSaleID { get; set; }
    public virtual int? StockPLU { get; set; }
    public virtual int? RecipeProductID { get; set; }
    public virtual int? SalesUnitID { get; set; }
    public virtual int PriceLevelID { get; set; }
    public virtual int QtyToBePaid { get; set; }
    public virtual int Quantity { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal SalesUnitCostPrice { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal TotalVAT { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal TotalVolume { get; set; }
    public virtual char IsSubSalesUnit { get; set; }

    public virtual OpenSale OpenSale { get; set; }
  }
}
```

**Child Map**

```
using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;
using Models;

namespace Maps 
{       
  public class OpenSaleItemMap : ClassMap<OpenSaleItem> 
  {    
    public OpenSaleItemMap() 
    {
        Table("OpenSaleItem");

        Id(x => x.ID).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("ID");

        Map(x => x.Quantity).Column("Quantity").Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.SalesUnitCostPrice).Column("SalesUnitCostPrice").Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.OpenSaleID).Column("OpenSaleID").Generated.Insert();
        Map(x => x.StockPLU).Column("StockPLU").Nullable();
        Map(x => x.RecipeProductID).Column("RecipeProductID").Nullable();
        Map(x => x.PriceLevelID).Column("PriceLevelID").Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.QtyToBePaid).Column("QtyToBePaid").Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.SalesUnitID).Column("SalesUnitID").Nullable();
        Map(x => x.TotalAmount).Column("TotalAmount");
        Map(x => x.TotalVAT).Column("TotalVAT");
        Map(x => x.TotalVolume).Column("TotalVolume");
        Map(x => x.IsSubSalesUnit).Column("IsSubSalesUnit");

        References(x => x.OpenSale).Column("OpenSaleID");
    }
  }
}
```

You will notice in the Parent Map there are alot of commented out lines of code, they are the mappings I tried but only the Parent records gets saved.

It is my goal that the parent object is created with multiple child objects and saved in one action.

There are workarounds - but would involve multiple database visits or creating a stored procedure and passing in the list of child items as a datatable but I would much rather prefer to stick to the one framework and use fluent NH.

Any help appreciated! thanks

Comment: Please don't be lazy - format code with proper indentation to make it easier to read for people that might attempt answering it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Inverse() it's important that you set up the relationship also in the client side. Have you assigned OpenSaleItem.OpenSale?

If that doesn't solve the problem, please update to show the actual code that attempts to perform the creations including session and transaction management.